Replicating Bayesian Regression between Stata and R
I have run the following Bayesian logistic regression in Stata. There are two dichotomous variables: exposure and outcome.
bayes, nchains(5) ///
        prior({excellent:tx}, normal(0,2))  ///
        rseed(123456) : ///
        logistic outcome exposure   

With the same dataset, I am trying to replicate this in R using the brms package:
priors <- c(
  set_prior("normal(0, 2)", class = "b", coef = "tx"),
  set_prior("normal(0, 10000)", class = "Intercept")
)
bayes_model <- brm(
  formula = outcome ~ exposure,
  family = bernoulli(link = "logit"),
  data = data,
  prior = priors,
  chains = 5,
  iter = 12500,  
  warmup = 2500,
  seed = 123456
)
summary(bayes_model)
plot(bayes_model)

#print exponentiated odds ratios
fixed_effects <- fixef(bayes_model)
odds_ratios <- exp(fixed_effects)
odds_ratios

However, I get very different estimates of the odds ratio between Stata and R. Can you please help me figure out why?
As best as I can tell, I am presenting the same data to each model, and I have specified the R code to replicate all of Stata's default settings (burn in period/warmup, prior for the intercept, underlying distribution).

normal(0, 10000) as a prior for logistic regression is a little crazy. Are you sure that is what Stata is doing? What happens instead if you change the model formula to outcome ~ 0 + exposure and prior to priors <- c(   set_prior("normal(0, 2)", class = "b") )?
